# Discard changes inside UITableView do not reflect on the cell with UITextView that is not visible but active

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have UITableView with UITableViewCells that contains UITextView. And I have logic for temporary data and saved data. So, when user edit that cells everything is working, including discarding changes that I do with swapping temporary data and saved data. Then I do reloadData on table view and everything is showed correctly.

My problem is when the user clicks on the textfield and scrolls the table view until the "active" text view cell is not visible and the changes are then discarded. What happens is that all is discarded, but the active cell has the latest data that is not discarded. If I put "cursor" on some other cell and then discard changes again, it'll be ok, all cells that aren't active will discard data.

So, discarding data is not working only on cell that is not visible but still has active uitextview.

I tried to get "latest" active cell and manually reload them but it's not working. I have tried to resignFirstResponder() from tableview and then discarding data and reloading tableview but it's not working.

I expect all text views inside the tableview to have old data that is not saved when I click `discard changes`.

Cell that is still active (with an active text view) and is not visible on the screen won't discard changes, it will still have old data (but it will not be active anymore)

EDIT:

Here is how everything is working.
Here is how my code is working (very simplified).

So, I have

`ViewModel -> ViewController -> Cell`

On viewModel i have:

```
var data = ["Some", "things", "are", "good"]
tempData = []
```

on `init` I put `tempData = data`

(we are here talking about structs so value types, and everything is working as I said regarding that)

on `cellForRow` I have

`cell.data = viewModel.data[indexPath.row]`

and If I click discard changes on viewController I just do this in viewModel:

```
data = tempData
```

and on ViewController

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

and everything is working.

Only thing that is not working is that active cell that is not on the screen. It's not affected by changes in "core" dataset.

So maybe there's a connection about UITableView can't refresh cells that have active UITextView and are not visible at the moment of reloadData()? I don't know about that.

EDIT2:
cellForRow

```
        guard let cell: ExampleTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(),
            let data = viewModel.data[safe: indexPath.row] else {
                return UITableViewCell()
        }

        cell.model = (name: data.name, surname: data.surname)

        cell.onTextViewDidChange = { [weak self] text in
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            self?.viewModel.update(text: text, index: indexPath.row)
        }

        return cell
```

Comment: So to clarify: Your model has the real data. When you show your view controller, the data is copied over and is stored in `tempData`. Your table view is populated by the model's data rather than the data that you just copied over.

I'm not clear on where the data that the user has changed is stored.

Comment: Oh sorry. Well pretty much everything regarding data is working. I have callback on cell that update data while it is edited. 

And if that cell is on the screen (as active) and I discard changes everything is ok. On viewModel set tempData as data, table got reloaded and all changes are discarded on every cell.

But problem is only when I edit some data on cell and then I swipe down or up and that cell is not visible anymore but it is still active (it's in edit mode on textview). Then, only that cell is not updated every other is (visible and non visible)

Comment: This is probably my bad but I still don't understand where the data is going. If you could post more code for how the cell updates the data when fields are edited, I think that would help me.

Comment: Well it's really specific problem. I added cell for row method. Data is updated correctly and everything is working besides reloadData() don't affect UITextView hidden Active cell. If cell is not active (textview is not in edit mode) than everything is showing correct. If cell is active and on screen reloadData is also working.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key features of UITableView is that it reuses the same instances of the cells over and over again, only keeping as many unique instances as it takes to simulate there being infinite instances. Notice how in `tableView(_: cellForRowAt: )` you do not initialize a cell, you `dequeue` it. This is because UIKit manages when the cells are initialized for the first time and when they are "recycled", hence `RecyclerView` on Android.

Without being able to look at your code, I would guess that the issue is that your temporary data is stored inside of an instance of the cell and when the cell scrolls offscreen, something is happening in your `tableView(_: cellForRowAt)` function which tells the cell to display a different cell's data and doesn't save the temporary data. My suggestion for a fix if this is the case would be to store the temporary data in your UIViewController rather than in the cell. It is also better MVC to store this kind of data in the controller rather than in the view.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment. I updated my question with some code